# Security of javascript / html of an app from windows 8 app store

Tags: javascript, windows-8, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

I'm developing an js/html app for win8 app store.

Is is possible to see/copy the js code I wrote?

Is it possible to access app's package and hack it? How to avoid it?

Comment: Yeah it is possible to get the code, Its inside windows apps folder in c drive.I'm not sure how to avoid it

Comment: @Prasanna Aarthi, may I ask the exact path to the apps folder?

Comment: here you go C:\Program Files\WindowsApps you will need Admin permission to continue to this folder

Answer (score 0):

You can obfuscate your code 
Just look for "js obfuscator" in an search engine and  you should find a good obfuscator
*And what is obfuscate?*
-It's turning your code uninteligible by humans.
See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscation and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscation_(software)

But obfuscating your code isn't tottaly secure. With some time and patience a hacker can get your code (an good example of obfuscated code is jquery, try to understand it!). I think that javascript can't be tottaly secure ,so, easier than obfuscate, register your code!